# C programming call function

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I'm new to C Programming and would like to learn the basics. Would anyone be able to help me on how to call a function that has a parameter which is a pointer?

The code that I have in `user.c` file:

```
struct user * play_game(struct user * first, struct user * second)
{
    game_board board;
    enum cell token;
    struct user * current, *other, *winner;
}
```

The code is also in `user.h` file but without the inside statement.
How would I be able to call it in the `main.c` file? I'm not sure what the parameters are and how it works.

Comment: What have you learned about the unary `&` and `*` operators?  What are the types of the variables in the `main()` program, because that will control how you call the function.  If you have `struct user *u1 = …; struct user *u2 = …;` you will use `struct user *winner = play_game(u1, u2);` — but if you have `struct user u1 = { … }; struct user u2 = { … };` you will use `struct user *winner = play_game(&u1, &u2);`.

Comment: my programming knowledge is really not good sorry. what i know for now is that if a variable got a * it means that its a pointer and for the & its for the address if im right. I tried to declare  struct user * play_game(struct user * first, struct user * second) before the main () and inside it i put the code user * play_game(struct user * first, struct user * second). Not sure if i describe it in a way you can understand it.

Comment: Your understanding of `*` and `&` is more or less accurate — crude but probably sufficiently good for the time being. Assuming you've defined `struct user` somewhere, you should be OK with the function declaration you show.  If you're getting a compilation error, you need to show us an MCVE ([MCVE]) — and the actual error message.  The line number should be small enough (say under 30) that it is easy for us to see what's going wrong.  If it isn't that small a line number, the chances are the code is not yet minimal enough.

Comment: sorry the code is supposed to be player and not user. "struct player * play_game(struct player * first, struct player * second). The errors i got is "error: unknown type name ‘player’" and "error: conflicting types for ‘play_game’".

Comment: Choose a name and make it consistent everywhere.  It sounds like you fixed the function in the source (`.c`) file but forgot to change the header (`.h`) file.

Comment: not sure on what you mean by "Choose a name and make it consistent everywhere". Do you want me to create a new variable inside the main()? In my main.c i already got the the "#include "main.h" wherein my main.h have the following codes 
"#include "shared.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "game.h"
#include "scoreboard.h"
#include "utility.h""

Comment: I mean choose a name for your structure type — either `struct user` or `struct player` — and be careful to make sure you use it everywhere that's appropriate.  There's nothing to stop you have two structure types (e.g. `struct user` and `struct player`) if that's appropriate — but you need to use the correct name at each place where you define a variable or function parameter or function return type, both in the source files and the header file (or header files if you have several).

Comment: found the file with the struct player in a different file which is player.h. and it goes like this 
" struct player
{
    char name[NAMELEN + 1];
    enum cell token;
    unsigned score;
}; "   in the player.c file i got " BOOLEAN init_first_player(struct player * first, enum cell * token)
{

} " so now i dont have an idea on how it is related from the first code i posted.

Comment: That, sadly, makes two of us.  Since I can't see all the code, it is not clear.  The name `player.h` sounds appropriate; is there also a function `init_second_player()` declared in there?  However, it sounds as if your main program should have code like: `struct player p1; struct player p2; if (init_first_player(&p1, …) && init_second_player(&p2, …)) { struct player *winner = play_game(&p1, &p2); … }`.  It is not remotely clear why you'd pass an `enum cell *` to the `init*` functions.  It isn't clear what the cell enum describes.  It isn't clear if the first player is always `X`, etc.

Comment: yes there is also another function/declaration in player.h " init_second_player() " and the last function is " BOOLEAN make_move(struct player * human, game_board board) ". For this program im doing it says that the code struct user * play_game(struct user * first, struct user * second) should be called first then ask the player for a name. Is it possible to send the zip file so you can check the start up code?

Comment: sent hopefull you can teach/tutor me on how things work on the code. thank you so much

Comment: On the whole, it's best to identify yourself — especially as your email bears no resemblance to your name on SO, and you've titled the file with the name of the game you're working on, but that name doesn't appear in this question.  Include a URL to the question, for example — at least it lets me know who I'm dealing with.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Its ken by the way and im starting to learn the basic of C Programming. Its my first post and first time using a forum so not quite familiar on how things go on here.

Comment: One thing that doesn't normally happen is that you get this much interaction; I'm more patient than the average person around here.  I suggest you delete this question, and ask a new question (or, over time, some new questions). You'll need to show the code that's causing you  trouble at the time, and your best effort at resolving it. The code should be minimal — I previously mentioned [MCVE] and your questions should include an MCVE. You need to understand the basics of creating structure variables (e.g. `struct player human;`) and passing their address to functions (`some_function(&human)`).

Comment: ok cool thank you for the information. ill try to post a new question its just that i dont know how to ask it properly. lol

Answer (score 0):

You should include user.h in main.c, and include user.h in user.c, in wich you implements functions, declared in user.h like in interface.

In the main.c you give two `struct user*` as parameters to your function.
 `struct user *var` is a usual variable with type of pointer, wich contains a some adress value. To initialize this pointer you can use `var = (struct user*)malloc(sizeof(*var))` or `struct user a; var = &a` construction. In the first case you allocate new struct on heap, and in second case you get adress of variable created on stack.

Some example of code wich calls your function:

```
struct user* result;
struct user* param1 = (struct user*)malloc(sizeof(*param1));
/* initialize ...*/
struct user param2;
/* initialize ...*/
result = play_game(param1, &param2);
```